# frequently crashing of pod in openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, openshift

**Getting this in log while deploying image in openshift:**

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.13. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
>
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
>
> (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   AH00015: Unable to open logs

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM httpd:2.4

RUN echo "hello app" > /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/hello.html
```

also getting the error if i use EXPOSE 80

Comment: What's situation if changed to 8000?

Comment: OpenShift isn't by default going to allow your image to run as `root`. It run as an assigned user ID. So an application that requires `root` to bind port 80 isn't going to work. https://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/why-do-my-applications-run-as-a-random-user-id.html

Comment: OpenShift provides in its catalog of image an Apache httpd image which has been designed to work in OpenShift, so perhaps use it. https://github.com/sclorg/httpd-container

Comment: httpd in a container normally has no need to run on 80 and 443 either, as k8s would usually have a service in front of the container. The `httpd` binary can be [given the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` capability](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/NonRootPortBinding) which will allow it to bind to ports < 1024 as a non root user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ports up to 1024 are so called `privileged ports` this means that in order to bind to them, the user has to have root capabilities.
In your case, you are trying have your service listen on port 80, which is in that `privileged` port range.
By default openshift is not running any containers inside the Pods as root.

You will either have to adjust the user as which it runs or have it listen on a different port.